# Hide row based on specific date SSRS

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, expression

I want to hide the details row of my SSRS report if the field 'duedate' equals a specific date (2001-01-01).  I know how to do this with Crystal syntax, I just can't wrap my head around how to make it work in SSRS.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In crystal it would be:

```
{command.duedate}=DateTime (2001,01 ,01 )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the Visibility-Hidden property to:

```
=IIF(Fields!DueDate.Value = CDate("2001-01-01"), True, False)
```

Beware if `DueDate` contains a time component, then you might need to strip that out using `DateValue`:

```
=IIF(DateValue(Fields!DueDate.Value) = CDate("2001-01-01"), True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another working approach is to create a field in the resultset as a flag ("Y" / "N" ) and use that field to filter the tablix (this method perhaps works better when nesting groups).